# mongomapper, rails3 edge: undefined method `to_key' on form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongomapper, devise

when i am trying to get the basic devise examples running with current git versions from rails, mongomapper and devise, i have the following error appearing:

```
undefined method `to_key' for #<Admin:0x23dee04>
```

here is my actual source:

```
4: = form_for @admin, :url => admins_path do |f| 
5:   - field_set_tag 'Update my email' do 
6:     %p= f.text_field :email 
7:     %p= error_message_on @admin, :email
```

@admin is the currently logged in user (@admin= current_admin) 
the same error occurs when trying to use @admin=Admin.first in the 
controller

i am not quite sure if this is a mongomapper problem, might also be 
rails3 related... 
thanks for any pointers...

the same happens if i am using the erb equivalent, see

```
<%= form_for @admin, :url => { :action => "create" } do |fr| %>
<%= fr.text_field :sign_in_count %> 
<% end %>
```

here is the full error output: http://pastie.org/871850

Comment: here is the thread i started on the mongomapper google group: http://groups.google.com/group/mongomapper/browse_thread/thread/3525e90db4149706?pli=1

Comment: ok, some more information on that topic after some research:

to_key is from ActiveModel
see http://github.com/rails/rails/commits/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/primary_key.rb

some folks at authlogic were discussing this. i think this might be an interesting read:
"There are some changes in the primary key handling in ActiveModel. They changed key to to_key."
http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/issues/issue/101/#comment_142986

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have submitted a patch to MongoMapper here:

http://github.com/fredwu/mongomapper/commit/6e5e531312ef98c30e33286a1f80dd000468ed07

Answer (score 1):

ok, here is a fix:

## 1 fix in the model

```
def to_key
  self.keys.to_a
end
```

## 2 fix in the view

```
<%= form_for :admin, @admin, :url => { :action => "create" } do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :sign_in_count %>
<% end %>
```

both will work. still it's not clear to me if this is a rails or mongomapper issue, but for anyone else running into this, here is a workaround.

Comment: ok as fred stated below, my patch is actually bollocks and his is the way to go ;) thanks!